# How to execute a function when Click Button (X) on Input Field search vuejs

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-component

I need to do an action when Click  Button (X) on search is clicked using Vue.

when he clicks on the input seach? on "x

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  
  data: {
    msg: 'the input is cleaned',
    info:''
  },
  
 
  methods: {
    handleClick: function(){
    // to do sonthing when is cleaned not before
        if(this.info=='')
      alert(this.msg)
    },
    
   
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="search" v-model="info" @click="handleClick" >
  <br>
  <span>{{ info }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi ! I did not understood this part of the question `I need to do an action when Click Button (X) on search is clicked using Vue`, could you phrase it differently please ? Do you want to have something running when the user have cleared the input, when he presses the key `X` (uppercase `x`) or simply when he clicks on the input ?

Comment: when he clicks on the input seach? on "x"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want to differentiate between a normal click inside a `input[type="search"]` and a click on its clear control. I've spent some time trying to compare the two clicks and I wasn't able to find how they differ.

But I came up with a trick to figure it out:

- if the input has a value (you need one for the clear button to be displayed)
- we wait for DOM to update and, after it did, if the input no longer has a value (it was cleared) => bingo! it was a clear search click.

Therefore:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    handleClick(e) {
      if (e.target.value) {
        this.$nextTick() // wait for DOM update
          .then(() => {
            if (e.target.value === '') {
              console.log('clear button clicked you must have, young Jedi!');
            }
          })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="search" @click="handleClick">
</div>
```

However, I believe you're better off with a watch on your `v-model`:

```
watch: {
  info(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (oldVal && !newVal) {
      console.log('info was cleared').
    }
  }
}
```

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({ info: '' }),
  watch: {
    info(newVal, oldVal) {
      if (oldVal && !newVal) {
        console.log('morning has broken...');
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="search" v-model="info">
</div>
```

It has the advantage it will not only trigger on `click`. It will trigger every time `info` changes from a truthy value to a falsy one, regardless of what caused the change (i.e: user selecting the text and pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd>; any other component method clearing it, resetting the input or the parent form, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

From the comment on the question, you're asking to call a function when the user clicks on the input field ? It's the way that I understood your question.

For that case, here is a quick demo on how to achieve that.
https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-lake-34bvi?file=/src/App.vue